# Incremental updates on GDAL VRT with overviews

Tags: raster, gdal, wms, raster-calculator, gdaladdo

I have quite a big GDAL VRT with a pyramid (TIFFs in smaller zoom levels stored externally in separate folders) and the calculation of those takes quite some time.

I am also having regular updates on the VRT and I don't want to calculate the complete pyramid, because its not necessary. So my question is, do gdal_retile or gdaladdo or any other GDAL tool have the possibility to recalculate all the overviews for one image within the pyramid?

Comment: You could build higher res overviews on the tifs for zoomed in views and lower res overviews on the vrt for displaying large areas https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/148343/2856

Comment: What are you trying to do in the end? I had the same issue but decided to use GroServer ImageMosaic instead of VRT.

Comment: I removed the vrt, because there was no advantage of having it. Now i am having the pyramid without a VRT file. The problem was, that as far as i know there is no script to update the overviews of this pyramid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, as far as I know there is not a ready-to-use solution to run incremental updates on a pyramid with gdal. So I wrote it on my own - the following script will execute gdal_retile only for the updated overviews:

```
    #new_file= original tif-file within the pyramid which should be updated        
    levels=[1, 2, 3, 4] #Zoom levels within the pyramid

    #1. Get the center of the tif-file as wkt-geometry        
    try:
       raster = gdal.Open(new_file)
       geoTransform = raster.GetGeoTransform()
       x_min = geoTransform[0]
       y_max = geoTransform[3]
       x_max = x_min + geoTransform[1] * raster.RasterXSize
       y_min = y_max + geoTransform[5] * raster.RasterYSize

    except RuntimeError, e:
       print 'Unable to open tif file'
       print e
       break

    x = (x_max + x_min) / 2
    y = (y_min + y_max) / 2
    wkt_point = 'POINT ({0} {1})'.format(x, y)   

    for level in levels:
       #The overviews of each level are in a separate folder (level_folder). In each folder is a shape file with the boundaries of the tiles and the path to the tif-file. 

       print 'Calculating overviews for level {0}'.format(level)

       level_folder = src_dir + '{0}/'.format(level)
       level_shape = level_folder + '{0}.shp'.format(level)

       #Load the shapefile and get the features intersecting with the center of the tif file (wkt_point) -> this will give you the names of the tifs which should be updated
       driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')    
       datasource = driver.Open(level_shape, 0)

       if datasource is None:
           print 'Error loading Level Shapefile'
           break

       level_layer = datasource.GetLayer()
       level_layer.SetSpatialFilter(ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt(wkt_point))

       for feature in level_layer:

           to_be_replaced_tile = level_folder + feature.GetField('location')     

           #here i am basically writing the files which should be updated to a txt-file. The txt-file is then passed to the gdal retile command 
           return_tuple = create_txt_file(update_dir, level, level_folder, feature.GetGeometryRef())

           txt_file = return_tuple[0]
           first_file_name = return_tuple[1]

           cmd = ' '.join(['\"C:/Program Files/QGIS 2.18/bin/python.exe\" \"C:/Program Files/QGIS 2.18/bin/gdal_retile.py\"','-r', 'bilinear', '-s_srs', 'EPSG:25832', '-ps', '8000', '8000', '-pyramidOnly', '-targetDir', update_dir, '--optfile', txt_file, '-levels', '1'])

           s_info = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
           s_info.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW

           try:

               subprocess.check_call(cmd, startupinfo=s_info)

           except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
               print 'error message: {0}'.format(e.output)

           new_file = update_dir + '/1/' + first_file_name.replace('.tif', '_1_1.tif')
           new_file = new_file.replace(resource_level_folder, update_dir)
           replace_file(to_be_replaced_tile, new_file)

       print 'finished writing files for level {0}'.format(level)

    def create_txt_file(update_dir, level, resource_level_folder, geom):

       driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')    
       datasource = driver.Open(resource_level_folder, 0)

       if datasource is None:
          print 'Error loading Shapefile'
          return None

       resource_level_layer = datasource.GetLayer()        
       target = osr.SpatialReference()
       target.ImportFromEPSG(25832)
       bbox = geom.Buffer(-1)

       resource_level_layer.SetSpatialFilter(bbox)
       list_tiles = []
       first_file_name = ''

       for resource_feature in resource_level_layer:

          if not first_file_name:
             first_file_name = resource_feature.GetField('location')

          list_tiles.append(resource_level_folder + resource_feature.GetField('location'))

       f = open(update_dir + '/update_level{0}.txt'.format(level), 'w')
       f.write("\n".join(list_tiles))
       f.close()

       return [update_dir + '/update_level{0}.txt'.format(level), first_file_name]
```

Comment: could you explain in words how the script is working ?

Comment: I added some comments and extended the code. Maybe its easier now...