# Creating overview images for individual rasters becomes more flexible when the layer is partially updated. How do I do this?

Tags: geoserver, gdal, gdalbuildvrt

I use a GeoServer.

I want to create a layer from a mosaic that I got using gdal from a vrt file that is created from pieces of a map whose size is 9 000 000 * 3 000 000 pixels.

To create a VRT file, I use gdalbuildvrt.

```
gdalbuildvrt file.vrt /*.tif
```

I plan to use gdal2tiles to create a mosaic.

This layer will only be displayed on a single scale that covers a small number of mosaic granules.

> The problem is that if I change one piece of the original map, I will
>   have to redo the entire mosaic, which will take a long time.

here [Overviews: to tiles or .vrt, or both?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/148303/overviews-to-tiles-or-vrt-or-both) this question was discussed, but I didn't understand how to do it.

Creating overview images for individual rasters becomes more flexible when the layer is partially updated. How?

*Is it possible to create a virtual mosaic from virtual VRT files and connect it to GeoServer?*

Comment: how often do you intend to change parts of the raster?

Comment: @IanTurton I think once a month. The process of creating the entire mosaic takes a very long time and I do not want to repeat it once again.